# jqGrid auto filter highlighting search result

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I want help in highlighting jqgrid row's data part as and when they are matched.

My jqGrid markup:

```
<div title="Environment variables">
    <div class="jqUIDiv">
        <table id="tblEnvvars" width="100%"></table>
        <div id="EnvvarsGridpager"></div>
    </div>
</div>'
```

And my jqGrid code:

```
var envVars=[]; //xml is a xml response sent from server
$(xml).children('product').each(function(){ 
    $(this).children('envvars').each(function(){ 
        $(this).children('variable').each(function(){ 
            var row={};
            isPresent=true;
            row.name=$(this).attr('name');
            row.value=$(this).attr('value');
            envVars.push(row);
        });
    });
});

jQuery("#tblEnvvars").jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",    
        data: envVars,
        colNames:['Name','Value'],
        colModel:[
            {name:'name',index:'name', align:"left"},   
            {name:'value',index:'value', align:"left"}

        ],
        pager : '#EnvvarsGridpager',
        rowNum:10,
        rowList:[10,50,100],
        scrollOffset:0,
        height: 'auto',
        autowidth:true,
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true

    });

    jQuery("#tblEnvvars").setGridParam({rowNum:10}).trigger("reloadGrid");
    jQuery("#tblEnvvars").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: 'cn'});
```

for example:

if a row item contains `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and user types in `LIB` in search area, then `LIB` in LD_LIBRARY_PATH should get highlighted.

**Update: 15/12/2011**

I found [this Highlight plugin](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html) to highlight but need help in applying it.

I used it to create the below screenshot

[image]

Here is the code i used

```
jQuery("#list1").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: 'cn', afterSearch:highlightIt()});

function highlightIt()
{
$('#list1 > tbody > tr > td').highlight('HOST');
}
```

Comment: What you mean under the "highlighting" of the row? If you select a row  of the grid the row will be highlighted by adding the class "ui-state-highlight" to the row. Is this what you want to have for many rows of the grid?

Comment: @Oleg - I think he wants to highlight text portions of data in the rows, when text is typed into a search box.

Comment: @Abhishek - Have you taken a look at the `filterToolbar` docs http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching - it looks like `beforeSearch` might be a good event to hook in your highlight plugin.

Comment: @Justin Ethier: Yes, i want to highlight text portions of data in a row, which matches the search text

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SearchPerJQueryAndSelect.htm) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3798151/315935). If you would use `beforeSearch` (see suggestion from the Justin Ethier comment) you can easy modify the demo to use `filterToolbar`.

**UPDATED**: After rereading of your question carefully one more time I fond your idea to highlight the search patterns very interesting. So I created [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/AbhishekSimon11.htm) which demonstrate how to implement your requirement. I used the options

```
loadonce: true,
ignoreCase: true
```

to make case insensitive local filtering of the data. If you use already local data types (any datatypes excepring `'xml'` and `'json'`) the data will be already hold locally and you don't need to add additional `loadonce: true` option.

Typing in the searching filter above the grid search patterns the data will be not only filtered by the patterns but the pattern part of very cell in the column will be highlighted which improves the visibility. So you can see the results like on the following picture:

[image]

Now about the implementation. First of all I use the [Highlight plugin](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html) which you found, but I changed the line

```
spannode.className = 'highlight';
```

to

```
spannode.className = 'ui-state-highlight';
```

to be more compatible to jQuery UI CSS.

I don't use any callback function of the [filterToolbar](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching#calling_convention) because all the callbacks will be called *before* the new grid body will be filled. The [filterToolbar](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching#calling_convention) fill `filters` part of the `postData`, set the `search` parameter of jqGrid to `true` and trigger `reloadGrid`. So one should highlight the data inside of `loadComplete` (or `gridComplete`) callback because at the moment all data which should be highlighted are in the grid. So I used [filterToolbar](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching#calling_convention) in the simple form

```
$("#list1").jqGrid('filterToolbar',
    {stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: 'cn'});
```

The implementation of `loadComplete` you find below:

```
loadComplete: function () {
    var filters, i, l, rules, rule, iCol, $this = $(this);
    if (this.p.search === true) {
        filters = $.parseJSON(this.p.postData.filters);
        if (filters !== null && typeof filters.rules !== 'undefined' &&
                filters.rules.length > 0) {
            rules = filters.rules;
            l = rules.length;
            for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                rule = rules[i];
                iCol = getColumnIndexByName($this, rule.field);
                if (iCol >=0) {
                    $('>tbody>tr.jqgrow>td:nth-child(' + (iCol + 1) +
                        ')', this).highlight(rule.data);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oleg: I want to highlight text portions of the data in a row as and when search string is typed (live).. eg: if i give search string as `LIB` it should highlight all the text `LIB` in that column, that contains `LIB` in it. Also as an example you can try [this page](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html) to see what i mean.. (though this page highlights only after one clicks, I need, as and when user enters a key in the search string)

Comment: Any ideas? I tried `beforeSearch` but i think in  my case it should be `afterSearch` since while typing it should highlight the text portion in the datagrid, but `afterSearch` is triggered as soon as the grid is created, I am not able to understand. Please help in your free time. Thanks

Comment: 1 very urgent request, I came to know about this problem today itself, [Check your example](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/AbhishekSimon11.htm) when there are a lot of rows in jqgrid and I expand the view from 10 to 50 and when I try to select 10th or 11th row, it does not respond, it happens the same way in my jqgrid too. Can you try clicking on the row which has name `asd` & `IIR Windows`? Try checking it in IE8 when I select 11th row it selects 10th row

Comment: @AbhishekSimon: The reason seems for me easy: both 10th and 11th rows "IIR Windows" and "asd" has the same id=10. It's error in the data (in [AbhishekSimon11.xml](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/AbhishekSimon11.xml)). You should just use **unique** ids only.

Comment: It looks like `onSelectRow` the id's are somehow same, which is causing the problem. What is going wrong here, can you please help?

Comment: The Id's for `IIRWindows` & `asd` is `702` & `687` which is getting assigned from `cfgId` which is different

Comment: @AbhishekSimon: It's not id duplicates in the data. The data has no ids at all. It's the main reason. The id duplicates are from the old bug in jqGrid. I'll try whether it's still exsit.

Comment: I remember you told me to have **unique id's** for each row, so I created a node `cfgId` having unique nos. `database sequence` and I assigned it to `cfgId` colModel does jqgrid explicitly needs to have `id` as colModel?

Comment: You can fix the problem by adding `id: "cfgId"` as additional property of `jsonReader`. Try with [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/AbhishekSimon11_.htm). If you would use more recent jqGrid like 4.3.3 which I used in the last demo the problem will not exist too.

Comment: Thanks Oleg, i'll try that 1st thing in morning tomorrow :)

Comment: Hello gentlemen, thanks for your question & answer, which I voted up. Are you able to understand how to implement this in JqGrid for PHP ? I unsuccessfully tried to do it. my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21522699/jqgrid-php-highlight-results-when-filtering-via-toolbar) explains in details what I did.