# How to get value of a dropdownlist on change in Jqgrid filter

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I've got a filter in my Jqgrid and when I change the dropdownlist in the filter I want a function to execute. The problem I got with the current code is that it uses the value before the change, and not the value after.

Currently I've got the following code:

```
    { name: 'STATUS', index: 'STATUS', sortable: false, width: 80, stype: 'select',
    searchoptions: { value: ":All;Active:Active;Not active:Not active",
                    dataEvents: [
                            { type: 'change',
                                fn: function() {
                                        alert($('#Jqgrid').getGridParam('postData').filters);
                                        }
                                    }
                                ] 
                    }
    },
```

Comment: What do you mean under "Jqgrid filter"? Do you use [toolbar searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching) or the [searching dialog](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching) which uses `jqFilter` method? Why you need to have the changed value after the change? Do you want to have  the value before the searching? It is not the same. Please describe more detailed what you do and what you need.

Comment: I was looking to get the value of the selected value in a dropdownlist in toolbar searching. I solved it by using $('#Jqgrid').getGridParam('postData').filters) in the loadComplete function.

Answer (score 0):

If you use toolbar searching you can use `beforeSearch` callback option of the [filterToolbar](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching) method. Inside of the method you can use `$('#Jqgrid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData').filters` to get and even to modify the filter *before* it will be used. You can look [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8953934/315935) as an example.

If you want to do some action *after* the filter is applied and the filtered data are loaded you should access the `postData.filters` inside of `loadComplete`. See [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8505932/315935) as an example.

Answer (score 0):

try to get the value with:

```
...
dataEvents: [
                        { type: 'change',
                            fn: function() {
                                    console.log("value", $(this).val(), $(this).find("option:selected").val());
                                    }
                                }
                            ] 
                }
...
```

depending wich jquery version is used.