# Is it possible to search locally in jqGrid with treeGrid installed

Tags: jqgrid, treegrid

I am using jqGrid with treeGrid. I have added a filterToolbar. I would like to search locally instead of having a server call. The [treegrid docs](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3atreegrid) say that, **"When we initialize the grid  and the data is read, the datatype is automatically set to local."** (This is regards to TreeGrid)

So, is it possible to implement local search with treeGrid. I tried the below configuration, but it is resulting in server calls.

My Configuration is

```
var grid = $("#grid").jqGrid({
    treeGrid: true,
    treeGridModel: 'adjacency',
    ExpandColumn: 'businessAreaName',
    ExpandColClick : true,
    url:'agileProgramme/records.do',
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'GET',
    colNames:['Id'
              , 'Business Area'
              , 'Investment'
              , 'Org'
              , 'Goal'
    ],
    colModel:[
/*00*/          {name:'agileProgrammeId',index:'agileProgrammeId', width:0, editable:false,hidden:true},
/*01*/          {name:'businessAreaName',index:'businessAreaName', width:160, editable:false},
/*02*/          {name:'programmeName',index:'programmeName', width:150, editable:false, classes:'link'},
/*03*/          {name:'org',index:'org', width:50, editable:false, classes:'orgHierarchy', sortable : false},
/*04*/          {name:'goal',index:'goal', width:70, editable:false}
    ],
    treeReader : {
        level_field: "level",
        parent_id_field: "parent", 
        leaf_field: "leaf",
        expanded_field: "expanded"
    },
    autowidth: true,
    height: 240,
    pager: '#pager',
    sortname: 'id',
    sortorder: "asc",
    toolbar:[true,"top"],
    caption:"TableGridDemo",
    emptyrecords: "Empty records",
    jsonReader : {
        root: "rows",
        page: "page",
        total: "total",
        records: "records",
        repeatitems: false,
        cell: "cell",
        id: "agileProgrammeId"
    }
});
```

And to implement the search toolbar

```
$('#grid').jqGrid('filterToolbar', {stringResult: true,searchOnEnter : true});
```

Would appreciate any help or any pointer on even if it is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most problem in the TreeGrid filtering is that it's not clear *what should be displayed in the TreeGrid* as the result of applying the filter. The standard behavior of applying filter to the grid consist from *removing* all non-filtered rows. Such behavior will be wrong in case of TreeGrid. In the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9473515/315935) to the close question I tried to explain the problem.

What one can try to implement is some kind of highlighting of the filtered rows only (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8505932/315935) as an idea) or one can set some CSS class to the non-filtered rows to make there gray (like disabled). In any way one have to display parents of the filtered rows in some way. One more option will be to display the filtered TreeGrid not in the Tree form. On can display for example an additional column with the path to the filtered row and the rest row data.

**UPDATED:** What I mean with "to display parents of the filtered rows" is about the following. Let us we have the TreeGrid like the following

```
+root             123
    +testchild1    32
        test1       4
    +child2        30
        test2       7
```

and we filter for the first column for the text "test". In the case it would be wrong to display just the lines which has the text "test"

```
    +testchild1    32
        test1       4
        test2       7
```

but in some scenarios if would be enough to display the above lines with the full path till the root element:

```
root\testchild1          32
root\testchild1\test1     4
root\testchild1\test2     7
```

In the case the information will be displayed in the grid instead of TreeGrid.

In other cases the searching in the leafs only can have sense. In the case one could really display the results in the TreeGrid form, but it will be not the common case.

Comment: Oleg, I did not clearly understand your last option, "One can display for example an additional column with the path to the filtered row and the rest row data."

Comment: @Nehu: I mean something like the following: if you would search in Windows in Explorer or in the Total Commender for a text some folders you will see in the result window the *full path* to the file which you found. You can try to generate the grid which would have the names of the all parents divided by '/'. I don't know which kind of information you display in the TreeGrid, but displaying the path to the item in some form can solve the problem which I described. I'll post an example in my answer.

Comment: @Nehu: I updated my answer. Do you thought about what will be the best result of TreeGrid filtering in case of *your* TreeGrid?

Comment: Oleg, Thank you very much for clarifying. This is an excellent idea. However, for my current scenario, I am still analyzing what would be the best way of filtering.

Comment: @Nehu: Like I wrote before the understanding what would be the best (in the specified scenario) to display as the result of filtering is the first thing what one have to clear.