# Universal search field for jqgrid

Tags: jquery, search, jqgrid

I'm new to jqgrid and I found out that there are four ways to implement a search in jqgrid:

```
a toolbar searching
a custom searching
a single field searching
a more complex approach involving many fields and conditions - advanced searching
```

I'd like to know if it's possible to implement a "google style" of universal search where you would only have one text field for search query. If I would write something to that field, it would try to search from all the data in the grid.

**EDIT**: I would like to fetch all the data once and use the search for that local data set.

See attached picture.

[image]

Comment: It's important to know which `datatype` you use. If you use `datatype: "json"` or `datatype: "xml"` without `loadonce: true` then you can access large dataset on the server, but *your server code* have to implement searching. jqGrid just send the searching parameter to the server and the server have to return filtered data. If you use other `datatype` value (mostly `"local"`) then jqGrid can search (filter) the data for you. Both solution are possible to implement, but the implementations are full different. Which one you need?

Comment: Thanks @Oleg! I'd like to load all the data at once and then do the search at client (browser) side.

Comment: Do you tried suggestions from my answer? Is it what you need?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are many ways to implement such requirement. I prepared two demos which demonstrates one from the possible solution: [the first one](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OneFieldSearching.htm) and [the next one](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OneFieldSearching1.htm). The second demo in enhanced version of the first one where I use [higlighting jQuery plugin](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html) in the same way like I describe it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8505932/315935).

First of all I add input box with the button to the top toolbar of the grid. I use `toolbar: [true, "top"]` to add an empty toolbar on the top of the grid. Then I use the following code

```js
$('#t_' + $.jgrid.jqID($grid[0].id))
    .append($("<div><label for=\"globalSearchText\">Global search in grid for:&nbsp;" +
        "</label><input id=\"globalSearchText\" type=\"text\"></input>&nbsp;" +
        "<button id=\"globalSearch\" type=\"button\">Search</button></div>"));
```

to fill the toolbar with the HTML fragment

```html
<div>
    <label for="globalSearchText">Global search in grid for:&nbsp;</label>
    <input id="globalSearchText" type="text">&nbsp;
    <button id="globalSearch" type="button">Search</button>
</div>
```

To start searching I used the following JavaScript code

```
$("#globalSearchText").keypress(function (e) {
    var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;
    if (key === $.ui.keyCode.ENTER) { // 13
        $("#globalSearch").click();
    }
});
$("#globalSearch").button({
    icons: { primary: "ui-icon-search" },
    text: false
}).click(function () {
    var rules = [], i, cm, postData = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "postData"),
        colModel = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel"),
        searchText = $("#globalSearchText").val(),
        l = colModel.length;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        cm = colModel[i];
        if (cm.search !== false && (cm.stype === undefined || cm.stype === "text")) {
            rules.push({
                field: cm.name,
                op: "cn",
                data: searchText
            });
        }
    }
    postData.filters = JSON.stringify({
        groupOp: "OR",
        rules: rules
    });
    $grid.jqGrid("setGridParam", { search: true });
    $grid.trigger("reloadGrid", [{page: 1, current: true}]);
    return false;
});
```

where `$grid` is the grid where we start searching (`var $grid = $("#list");`).

To improve a little the visibility of the elements in the top toolbar I used such simple additional CSS

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-userdata { height: auto; }
.ui-jqgrid .ui-userdata div { margin: .1em .5em .2em;}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-userdata div>* { vertical-align: middle; }
```

The results looks like on the picture below

[image]

[The second demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OneFieldSearching1.htm) uses higlighting plugin to improve visibility of the grid so that the user sees immediately where in the row the searched field are found:

[image]

One can sees that during creating of searching filter I skipped columns which have `search: false` property (like `"note"` column) and the columns having `stype: "select"`. I used `"cn"` (contains) filter in all columns.

Answer (score 4):

Yes this is possible - and quite simple I might add. Just place a textbox above your grid (or where ever you want it):

`<input type="text" id="search-string" name="search-string" />`

And a search button:

`<a href="#" id="search-button">Search</a>`

And here is the jQuery you need for the click event of that button:

```
$("#search-button").button().click(function(){
    searchString = $.trim($("#search-string").val());

    // check to see a search term has been entered in the textbox
    if(searchString == ""){
        alert("Please enter a word or phrase before searching!");
        // reset search box value to empty
        $("#search-string").val("").focus();
    }
    else{
        // set your grid's URL parameter to your server-side select file (that queries the DB)
        // we pass one parameter - the search string from the textbox
        $("#your-grid").jqGrid('setGridParam',{url:'crud/full-text-search.php?searchString='+searchString});
        // This line may need to be changed (if you use XML instead of JSON) 
        // It will reload the grid, using the new URL with the search term parameter
        $("#your-grid").jqGrid('setGridParam',{datatype:'json'}).trigger('reloadGrid');  
    }
});
```

Of course, in your server side file that queries the DB, you will need to grab that URL parameter containing the search string, and build your query with the correct `WHERE` clause...

Comment: Thanks @FastTrack for your answer! This is good solution if I want to do another query to the server, thanks for that. I was mainly looking for a solution to do a local search once I have fetched all the data at once. Sorry for not being clear enough. I have updated the question.

Comment: Ahh ok, I understand. Unfortunately, I won't be able to provide a good answer for searching through local data. I know @Oleg will though - he's a jQGrid whiz!

Comment: This is simple and elegant. I just have changed the postData using setGridParam and its working !!

Comment: @HappyCoder awesome! good luck with all your future jQGrid work