# Datatable like search box in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, search, jqgrid, datatables

I have been implementing jQgrid in the admin side of some of the applications and now I need to implement dataTables like searching feature in the grid. I tried with jQgrid default search but it is different from data table implementation and it has only one search box for filtering multiple columns. Is this possible in jQgrid

Comment: could you formulate more clear what you need and what you tried? What you mean under "dataTables like searching"? What you mean under "jQgrid default search" which you tried in jqGrid? Do you tried [Filter Toolbar](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching), [Searching dialog](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:singe_searching), [advanced searching dialog](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching), ...

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand you correctly, but probably [the old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19728244/315935) do what you need.