# jqGrid EditCell and highlight

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I use jqGrid 4.13.4-pre - free jqGrid by Oleg.

```
cellsubmit : 'remote',
datatype: 'json',
```

How to solve problem in a line of the  tags when cell editing?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you highlighte the searched text in the way close to described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19728244/315935). As the result the text of the cell contains HTML fragments with `<span class="ui-state-highlight">...</span>`.

You can use `formatCell` callback to make any changes in the editing cell value. The callback like the following should solve your problem:

```js
formatCell: function (rowid, cellname, value) {
    return $.jgrid.stripHtml(value);
}
```

By the way I recommend to update jqGrid from "4.13.4-pre" version to the corresponding released version "4.13.4" directly after publishing of the new release. Alternatively you can update to the latest 4.13.5-pre from GitHub.

Comment: Thank you. I will do in the evening, then I will write about result