# JqGrid PHP: how to implement a righ-click context-menu?

Tags: php, jquery, jqgrid, contextmenu, jqgrid-php

How can I implement a righ-click **context-menu** in JqGrid for PHP ?

I am trying [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6608787/3048495) by [Oleg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/315935/oleg), but it is not working.
I would like to get this:

[image]

---

**grid.php** snippet:

```
$rightclick = <<<RIGHTCLICK
    function () {
    $("tr.jqgrow", this).contextMenu('myMenu1', {
        bindings: {
            'edit': function (trigger) {
                // trigger is the DOM element ("tr.jqgrow") which are triggered
                grid.editGridRow(trigger.id, editSettings);
            },
            'add': function ( /*trigger*/ ) {
                grid.editGridRow("new", addSettings);
            },
            'del': function (trigger) {
                if ($('#del').hasClass('ui-state-disabled') === false) {
                    // disabled item can do be choosed
                    grid.delGridRow(trigger.id, delSettings);
                }
            }
        },
        onContextMenu: function (event /*, menu*/ ) {
            var rowId = $(event.target).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id");
            //grid.setSelection(rowId);
            // disable menu for rows with even rowids
            $('#del').attr("disabled", Number(rowId) % 2 === 0);
            if (Number(rowId) % 2 === 0) {
                $('#del').attr("disabled", "disabled").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
            } else {
                $('#del').removeAttr("disabled").removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}
RIGHTCLICK;

$grid->setGridEvent('loadComplete ', $rightclick);
```

Is there any way to get a context menu in JqGrid for PHP ?

Comment: Do you solved [your previous problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21522699/315935) with usage `this` inside of callback function which you set by `setGridEvent`? Probably you have the same problem here?

Answer (score 2):

First of all your code have unneeded space: `'loadComplete '` instead of `'loadComplete'`.

I can repeat one more time that I don't use PHP myself and don't use `setGridEvent` of JqGrid for PHP too. So I can only guess that `$grid->setGridEvent` probably don't forward `this` correctly. In the case you can use `setGridParam` to set callback dynamically (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3149534/315935)) or to use `jqGridLoadComplete` event instead of `loadComplete` callback (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6778789/315935)).

Comment: thank you @Oleg, I changed it to `loadComplete` without the space. Though, I am now getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLTableElement> has no method 'editGridRow'`

Comment: to fix the error above i had to change `grid.editGridRow(trigger.id, editSettings);` into `jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('editGridRow', '" + trigger.id + "');`  **Altough** I am now getting an empty edit form! (looks like the code doesn't get the row id!)

Comment: Ok I managed to get it working eventually! I had to change `'" + trigger.id + "'` to `trigger.id`.
therefore the right code is: `jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('editGridRow', trigger.id);`

Comment: @JessStone: One have to use `$("#grid").jqGrid("method", ...)` instead of `$("#grid").method(...)` if the option `$.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;` are set. Other parts of your code which you posted seems be far from the main question which I answered. Such problems could be easy debugged and it's much more difficult to find errors during reading. In any way I'm glad to read that you code seems to work now. My congratulations!