# Both Image and Select Formatter in jqgrid column

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm using jqgrid(Form editing) with dynamic `colmodel` in which i have to show a image inside a cell if necessary based on some values for which the same cell has the edit type as `select`.

So, the image should be shown in the grid when in view and during edit the cell should be turned as `select`. Not sure how to use the `formatter`.

//Code:

```
  case 'dropdown':    
                  colname.push({   
                            name: this.Name, index: this.Name, width: 130, edittype: "select", formatter: 'select', editoptions: { value: ':Select;' + this.ValueList.slice(0, -1) }, stype: 'select', searchoptions: { value: ':All;' + this.ValueList.slice(0, -1) }, align: 'left', sortable: true });

                        break;
```

The above code is used for creating the cell as `select` format during edit. Now i have to add a image inside the same cell.

Have to add the image `formatter` something like this?. Not sure where.

//Code:

```
formatter: function () {
                return "<img src='http://myserver/path/i.jpg' alt='my image' />";
            }
```

I have tried like adding the `formatter` as it is in the above mentioned code but its showing only the image and not the actual text of the column and in the edit i couldn't load the desired selected text.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) plugin which allows creating very comfortable selects with images (see [here](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#templating)) and searching inside of select options. [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19427444/315935) (see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/UsageFormetterSelect2.htm)) and [the another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19404013/315935) demonstrates how to use select2 inside of form editing, searching dialog and the filter toolbar.